# Can you detect whether a browser is "logged into" Facebook, Google+ or Twitter? (I.e., they could use an existing FB login if your site offered it?

Tags: facebook, registration

I'm considering implementing "Login with Facebook" (or Twitter or Google+) but I'd like to see what percentage of our users even have any of those.

(Our users tend to be fairly old and non technical and I *suspect* most don't have FB accounts.)

Answer (score 3):

[It is possible](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/02/an-interesting-way-to-determine-if-you-are-logged-into-social-web-sites/) to know programmatically if you are logged into social web sites.

Check the header (and then the HTML source) of this [WSJ microsite](http://datatransparency.wsj.com/) to see what other user details besides your current login status on social web sites can be tracked (I found it creepy so I now use a [Google Mobilizer Bookmarklet](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html) when I visit domains that are not on my whitelist).

I haven't tried it but there is a ready-made JavaScript library, [SocialHistory.js](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/socialhistoryjs/), to make this detection easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this information because cookies are private for every site.

Immagine that Facebook will analyze how many users goes in your site through cookies, you'll be happy of it?